# Returning URL Parameters from CURL response

Tags: php, curl

How do I get the URL Parameters from CURL response.

When I Send data, I use `POST` method to `example.com` .

But the Response they are sending back is in following structure. **But How can I get that?**

`example.com/?newParamKey1=value1&newParamKey2=value2`

I want to read **newParamKey1** & **newParamKey2**

CURL Code for `POST`ing data

`$postData['return_url'] = "http://return_data_in_this_url.com";`

```
    curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "http://example.com"); 
    curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
    curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, http_build_query($postData));
    curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
     $status = curl_getinfo($ch);
    curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 2);
    $return_data = curl_exec($ch);
```

Thirdparty is sending back response in the following structure.

http://return_data_in_this_url.com/?newParamKey1=value1&newParamKey2=value2

`curl_getinfo($ch)`

```
Array ( [url] => https://....../thirdpartyurl.php 
        [content_type] => [http_code] => 0 
        [header_size] => 0 
        [request_size] => 0 
        [filetime] => 0 
        [ssl_verify_result] => 0 
        [redirect_count] => 0 
        [total_time] => 0 
        [namelookup_time] => 0 
        [connect_time] => 0 
        [pretransfer_time] => 0 
        [size_upload] => 0 
        [size_download] => 0 
        [speed_download] => 0 
        [speed_upload] => 0 
        [download_content_length] => -1 
        [upload_content_length] => -1 
        [starttransfer_time] => 0 
        [redirect_time] => 0 
        [redirect_url] => [primary_ip] => [certinfo] => Array ( )            
        [primary_port] => 0 
        [local_ip] => [local_port] => 0 
      )
```

Comment: submit your full curl code!!

Comment: If you want to simply read the query-string parameters .. You can simly do that by using $_GET. Please see my answer!

Comment: Any Body know `CURLINFO_EFFECTIVE_URL` about this ? Will it help me?. I tried. No positive response.

Answer (score 0):

In PHP you can read the query string parameters in your PHP code in this way :

```
<?php

  if(isset($_GET["newParamKey1"]){
     $var1 = $_GET["newParamKey1"];
   }
  if(isset($_GET["newParamKey2"]){
     $var2 = $_GET["newParamKey2"];
   }    
?>
```

Comment: I am posting data to example.com, They are returning data through URL parametrs `?result1=1 & result2=2`. Read my Qn again Pls.

Comment: Does that come in the URL of your browser ?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5159122/best-method-to-send-get-params-to-url-and-get-returned-results-in-php

Comment: Yes When I tested Using Simple HTML Form, I am getting response through URL Parameter. ie) After I post to example.com, I was redirected to the original Form URL with `?result1=1 & result2=2`

Comment: Then I don't see any problem in why you can't use the above code?

Comment: I have set `curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);`  `curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 1);` also. No get params Available in those

Comment: I tried. Its not working. Am talking about cURL in PHP

Comment: I am sorry then.Only one last suggestion. Try using $_SERVER["key"]

Answer (score 0):

Since the site is returning you an URL with the POST/GET in key=>value pair you can simply store the object into an variable as shown below

`$postObject=$_REQUEST;`

and then run foreach loop as shown below

`foreach($postObject as $key=>$val)
{
   echo $key.' = '.$val;
}`

hop this will solve your problem

Comment: I tried `print_r($_REQUEST)`  and result is `Array()` Empty array

Comment: `eregi("newParamKey1",$return_data)` to check if the key is present in the return curl url

Comment: My Question is how to get the `$return_data` if server is appending it to a URL parameter. Please read the Question.